# Ruby smart variables

Tags: ruby

I like to see the value of my variables, so I write

```
puts "count=#{@count}"
```

Is there a way that I can say

```
@count.puts
```

or with some other method name, and get the output

```
count=77
```

Comment: It is not possible to do that in a ‘chained form’ without extra wrapping objects. This is because messages are sent to (methods are called upon) objects, not variables. Variables are first evaluated to values.

Comment: However, what about something like ‘pputs :@count’? The “pputs” would have to be a member of the current object (mixing or otherwise). It could then access the instance variable dynamically (on the current instance) and print the desired string. Note that a symbol representing the variable is supplied, and not the variable itself.

Comment: whats wrong with doing `puts "count=#{@count}"` ?